# Scroll disabled working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll

URL: http://bit.ly/1GUzfPx

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #201E24;
    }
.grid-view {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.library .list {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Although my page structure and CSS is quite simple but I just can't find whats blocking the scroll on Chrome and Android. Been scratching my head over this for a while now.

Comment: Why are you using `overflow: hidden;` if you want to be able to scroll vertically? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: To clear the float, but removing it doesn't have any effect either.

Comment: Removing it in inspector worked for me. I disabled `overflow:hidden` in `media="all"  body, .ionic-body` and now I can scroll.

Comment: Ah, that helped, but some of the the bottom elements are still not visible, must be something else hiding them.

Comment: Which page are you looking at? Seems fine to me.

Comment: On Chrome (mac) and Android it has issues. Looks good on Safari and iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have removed `overflow:hidden` in `media="all" body, .ionic-body` please try the following:

- Add `height:100%` to `html,body`
- Remove `height: 1052px;` from the inline styling of `content has-header grid-view`

And hopefully that sorts it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your problem, but try this.

```
.library .bar-clear{
  background:#35323A;
  position:relative;
}

.has-header{
  top:0px;
}
```